# My two admob accounts get terminated because of invalid activity, can I create a 3rd admob account and to link with that playstore account?

Tags: google-adsense

Last month my Admob account get terminated because of invalid activity and then I create new admob account which also got terminated because of invalid activity.

When I checked how my app was violating admob ads policy, it was because I had placed ADMOB BANNER very close to screen data. When a user clicked on the screen content then that banner would possible been clicked.

Now I have created another admob account and I have also fixed my app screen BANNER issue.

Will Google also terminate my this new account?

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it is about your mobile app and not about your website.